# OpenGL Multiple Textures Loading Error

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have a Model2D class which contains the following:

```
class Model2D
{
    public: //it's private, but I'm shortening it here
    unsigned char* bitmapImage;
    unsigned int textureID;
    int imageWidth, imageHeight;

    void Load(char* bitmapFilename);
}
void Model2D::Load(char* bitmapFilename)
{
    ifstream readerBMP;
    readerBMP.open(bitmapFilename, ios::binary);
    //I get the BMP header and fill the width, height

    bitmapImage = new GLubyte[imageWidth * imageHeight * 4];
    //Loop to read all the info in the BMP and fill the image array, close reader

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, imageWidth, imageHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapImage);
}
void Model2D::Draw()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);          
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);

    float texScale = 500.0; //this is just so I don't have to resize images

    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-(imageWidth / texScale), -(imageHeight / texScale), 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-(imageWidth / texScale), (imageHeight / texScale), 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f((imageWidth / texScale), (imageHeight / texScale), 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f((imageWidth / texScale), -(imageHeight / texScale), 0.0);    
}
```

And in my main loop, I have:

```
Model2D spritest;
spritest.LoadFromScript("FirstBMP.bmp");
spritest.Z(-5); spritest.X(-2);

Model2D spritest2;
spritest2.LoadFromScript("SecondBMP.bmp");
spritest2.X(+2); spritest2.Z(-6);

//...
//main loop
spritest.Draw();
spritest2.Draw();
```

While debugging it seems to be working fine, the addresses of the bitmaps are different, and so are the textureIDs that OpenGL generates, and they're being called correctly as well, and the X, Y and Z positions are also correct while debugging, but for some unknown reason, **spritest** image data is being overwritten by **spritest2**.
Even if I don't call Draw() from **spritest2**, the image is being displayed instead of **spritest**.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glBegin` must come after your texture binding functions in `Draw`:

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
```

In the documentation for [glBindTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindTexture.xml) it states:

> When a texture is bound to a target, the previous binding for that target is automatically broken.

You'll also find that in the documentation for [glBegin](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml) it states:

> Only a subset of GL commands can be used between `glBegin` and `glEnd`. The commands are `glVertex`, `glColor`, `glSecondaryColor`, `glIndex`, `glNormal`, `glFogCoord`, `glTexCoord`, `glMultiTexCoord`, `glVertexAttrib`, `glEvalCoord`, `glEvalPoint`, `glArrayElement`, `glMaterial`, and `glEdgeFlag`. Also, it is acceptable to use `glCallList` or `glCallLists` to execute display lists that include only the preceding commands. If any other GL command is executed between `glBegin` and `glEnd`, the error flag is set and the command is ignored.

Because of this, in your `Draw` function, you're going to need to place `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);` and `glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);` before `glBegin(GL_QUADS)`.  Otherwise, `glBindTexture` does nothing because it's within a `glBegin` and therefore `SecondBMP.bmp` is still bound to the target `GL_TEXTURE_2D`

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been looking through various tutorials for a while and I wasn't paying any attention already to the Draw code, thinking it was something in my texture loader...

Comment: Not to forget, that there's not bracing glEnd to finish the drawing operation.